# MySQL constraints involving multiple columns

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have a table in an application for which the current schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE quotes
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  quote_request_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  quote_amount DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL,
  accepted TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY (quote_request_id) REFERENCES quote_requests(id)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

I want to enforce a constraint such that only one quote can be accepted for a given quote request - i.e. an UPDATE or INSERT query should fail if it attempts to modify the table such that two or more rows with the same `quote_request_id` value will have an `accepted` value of 1.

Is this possible in MySQL? Enforcing constraints such as foreign keys, uniqueness of columns other than the primary key etc. work fine, and I can find information about applying a UNIQUE constraint to multiple columns, but I can't find anything about more complex constraints which involve multiple columns.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without reverting to a trigger in MySQL because MySQL does not support partial indexes.

Comment: Hmm, that's rather frustrating, though useful to know. Could you re-post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by a_horse_with_no_name, but in a comment so it can't be accepted:

"I don't think this is possible without reverting to a trigger in MySQL because MySQL does not support partial indexes."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without triggers, you can add another table where only accepted quotes will be stored - and you can remove the `accepted` column from the `quotes` table:

```
CREATE TABLE quotes
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  quote_request_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  quote_amount DECIMAL(12, 2) NOT NULL,
  --- accepted TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,             --- removed
  FOREIGN KEY (quote_request_id) REFERENCES quote_requests(id)
  UNIQUE KEY (quote_request_id, id)               --- needed for the FK below
) Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE quotes_accepted
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  quote_request_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (quote_request_id),            --- this ensures there is only one
                                            --- accepted quote per request
  FOREIGN KEY (quote_request_id, id) 
    REFERENCES quotes(quote_request_id, id)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: That would work, but I think the trade-off of an additional schema and the costs of that probably outweigh the benefit of having the constraint in the database.

I did also try using the CHECK option, but apparently MySQL accepts it (i.e. it's valid syntax) but ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want a `UNIQUE` like this:

```
UNIQUE `quote_accepts` (`quote_request_id`, `accepted`)
```

where, for a repeat pair of `quote_request_id` & `accepted`, the `INSERT` will fail.

Comment: Not quite, because that would only allow a maximum of two quotes to be entered for the same quote request (one where `accepted = 0` and another where `accepted = 1`), whereas I do not want to set a limit on the number of quotes where `accepted = 0`.